# How can I fix 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'get_performance'

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

I am having dificulty importing model in template tag..
`get_performance` is a model method in users model. I am trying to import the model so that I can use get_performace but this is the error I am getting `'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'get_performance'`

````
    .........................
    fields
    .........................

    def get_performance(self, timezone.now() + timedelta(days=-2), timezone.now()):

        actual = Sum("scores", filter=Q(status="completed"))

        q = self.taskassignt.filter(
            due__gte=timezone.now() + timedelta(days=-2),
            due__lt=timezone.now() 
        ).annotate(actual=actual, total=Sum("scores"))

        return (q[0].actual / q[0].total) * 100

Here is my template tag

from django import template
from django.utils import timezone
from datetime import timedelta
from ..models import User

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def performance(user, start_time=timezone.now() + timedelta(days=-2), end_time=timezone.now()):
    user = User.objects.all()
    return user.get_performance(timezone.now() + timedelta(days=-7), timezone.now())```
````

Comment: `User` is not the logged in user, but a `Queryset` of *all* users, so a *collection*, it thus makes no sense to call `.get_performance` on `user`.

Comment: You need to `.get()` a single user, not `.all()` of them.